# How to group tuples with adjacent indices in a python 2-dimensional tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

How to group tuples with adjacent indices in a python 2-dimensional tuple?

I'm not familiar with the zip function yet. I've written the code like this, but it doesn't work very well. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

```py
coords = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8))
coords = tuple(zip(coords[0::2], coords[1::2]))
print(coords)
```

real output:

```
(((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((5, 6), (7, 8)))
```

expected output:

```
((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code was almost there. This is one way you can make it work,

```
coords = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8))

coords = tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(coords[0::2], coords[1::2]))
```

Like in your code, it loops through two slices of `coords` using `zip`. But now it takes each element of the two slices (`x` and `y`) and adds them to form a 4 element inner tuple.

Answer (score 2):

This code would solve the problem:

```
coords = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8))
coords = tuple([(tuple([i for i in coords[x]])+tuple([i for i in coords[x+1]])) for x in range(0,len(coords)-1,2)])
print(coords)
```

Output:

```
((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8))
```